# SSH connection automatically closed when a command returns an exit status different from 0

Tags: ssh, connection

When I execute a command (e.g. : grep, cat, ...) on my VPS server that returns an exit status other than 0, my SSH connection is automatically closed.
I have no idea what could involve this issue...

Have you already experimented such kind of issue? Any suggestion?

---

Hereby the demonstration of this issue:

1) I connect to my VPS server from my computer:
sylvain@mycompute

```
sylvain@mycomputer:~$ ssh myuser@vps-server
Last login: Sat Sep  9 17:02:30 2017 from 11.22.33.44
myuser@vps-server:~$
```

2) I create a script that gets the exit status from the 1st parameter:

```
myuser@vps-server:~$ chmod u+x /tmp/test-exit-status.sh 
myuser@vps-server:~$ cat /tmp/test-exit-status.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Exit status will be '$1'."
exit $1
```

3) When exit status **is 0**, the SSH connection is kept:

```
myuser@vps-server:~$ /tmp/test-exit-status.sh 0
Exit status will be '0'.
myuser@vps-server:~$
```

4) When exit status **is NOT 0** (e.g. 56), the SSH connection is automatically closed and, on my computer, the exit status of the SSH command is the exit status of the script:

```
myuser@vps-server:~$ /tmp/test-exit-status.sh 56
Exit status will be '56'.
Connection to vps-server closed.

sylvain@mycomputer:~$ echo $?
56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if you have `set -e` in your `~/.bashrc`

Try doing `set +e` and re-running your test to see if it does the same thing again.

I'd consider adding explicitly `set +e` (or removing a `set -e`) in your `~/.bashrc` to permanently fix it.

Comment: Thanks! With your help, I locate the issue.

I had created a script /etc/profile.d/login-notify.sh that is invoked when any user login.
After commenting the line "set -e", the issue is solved.

I thought that, after exiting this script, this command "set -e" would be discarded.

Comment: If it was run as a separate script, that would be the case. However the profile snippets are sourced in the current shell as they're intended to change the current environment.